# Troubles in installing python-sybase module

Tags: python, sybase

I am trying to install this module simply following the installation guide:
http://    python-sybase.sourceforge.net/sybase/node5.html
I get an error that I don't understand, I am wondering if it's not a firewall problem but I don't know how to handle that:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\lippela\Desktop\python-sybase-0.39>python setup.py ins
tall

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
This script requires setuptools version 0.6c6 to run (even to display
help).  I will attempt to download it for you (from
http:  //cheeseshop.python.org/packages/2.4/s/setuptools/), but
you may need to enable firewall access for this script first.
I will start the download in 15 seconds.

(Note: if this machine does not have network access, please obtain the file

   http://  cheeseshop.python.org/packages/2.4/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c6-py2.4.egg

and place it in this directory before rerunning this script.)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading http:  //cheeseshop.python.org/packages/2.4/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c6-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 31, in ?
    use_setuptools()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\lippela\Desktop\python-sybase-0.39\ez_setup.py
", line 86, in use_setuptools
    egg = download_setuptools(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\lippela\Desktop\python-sybase-0.39\ez_setup.py
", line 140, in download_setuptools
    src = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\urllib2.py", line 130, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\urllib2.py", line 358, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\urllib2.py", line 376, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\urllib2.py", line 337, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\urllib2.py", line 1021, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\urllib2.py", line 996, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error (11001, 'getaddrinfo failed')>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The setup script failed to download the .egg it tries to download. It also tells you what to do when that happens: download the file yourself and place it in the same directory as the script.

Comment: Actually it can't download setuptools but it is the same issue and solution

Comment: Yes, the .egg it tries to download is the .egg for setuptools.